# flight deck st 4400 shifter replacement

Tags: shifter

flight deck st 4400 shifter not working. I have sprayed it and a man said is was US. What other shifters can I use new or used. I do not need the electrics cheers Steve

Comment: rh 9 speed double

Comment: Then you need a 9 speed brifter given its the right-hand one.  Given your current one is unserviceable, I'd recommend opening it and having a go.  You might be pleasantly surprised if it comes back to life.   Have a look at this linked video  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/37060/19705

Answer (score 2):

It's my understanding that all Shimano shifters below 11 speed ([except ST-4700][1]) use the same cable pull ratio. This means you can use any Shimano 9 speed rear brake/shifter unit.

Tiagra ST-4400 obviously and ST-4500, and Sora ST-3400 and ST-3500.

The newer Sora may be as good as the older Tiagra. Some googling and looking on Ebay may yield a replacement matching ST-4400. Or you maight choose to upgrade both brake/shifter units.

Comment: Thanks so much Argenti,I had a friend dismantle and reassemble but now no go at all. Do you have a complete breakdown of the parts plates and springs so I can clean and reassemble. It appears there is nothing at all broken he said,thanks so much Steve.

Comment: That probably should be asked as a separate question as this site is not supposed to be used like a discussion forum - but - Shimano has a [tech docs site](http://si.shimano.com/#/), I searched for 'ST-4400' and came up with an [exploded parts diagram](http://si.shimano.com/pdfs/ev/EV-ST-4400-1885.pdf) that may help you. Searching on YouTube for someone repairing a shift unit may also yield results